# Typescript error on class inherit and static methods

Tags: typescript

I'm facing a typescript error when compiling the following exemple:

```
class A {
  public static then() {
    return this;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  public static shouldWorks() { return 42; }
}

console.log(B.then().shouldWorks());
```

the compiler returns:

```
error TS2339: Property 'shouldWorks' does not exist on type 'typeof A'.
```

but when I try to execute the compiled script, it works !

what's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in static methods is not polymorphic. So `this` will just be `typeof A` when returning the class from `then`, and thus the methods added in `B` will have no impact on this class.

You can simulate polymorphic `this` by adding a type for the `this` parameter. The type of `this` will be a type parameter inferred from the call site:

```
class A {
    public static then<TThis extends new (...a: any[]) => A>(this: TThis) {
        return this;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static shouldWorks() { return 42; }
}

console.log(B.then().shouldWorks());
```

Comment: A way to get the same behaviour with getter  ?

Comment: @Nicolas unfortunately no. You can't specify `this` for a getter

Comment: I also facing a weird bahaviour, inside the function I can't access properties of `this` but outside (after returning `this`) it works, (in runtime both works)